# JSON PHP Not parsing correctly

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON I want to decode, but for some reason I can't access the object once I've decoded it.

JSON:

```
<?php 
$data = '{"error":null,"miningSpeeds":[{"coinTypeCode":"HXC","currentHash":"5 Gh/sec","miningTime":"The last coin switch was 4 minutes ago.","port":"Connect via port 3326 (Keccak)."},{"coinTypeCode":"LOT","currentHash":"9823 Kh/sec","miningTime":"The last coin switch was 44 minutes ago.","port":"Connect via port 3332 (Scrypt)."},{"coinTypeCode":"MZC","currentHash":"11 Th/sec","miningTime":"The last coin switch was 20 minutes ago.","port":"Connect via port 3331 (SHA256)."}]}'

$j = json_decode($data, true);

echo($j['miningSpeeds'][2]);
?>
```

Comment: Missing semi-colon at the end of your JSON string line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$j['miningSpeeds'][2]` returns an array and you can't make use of `echo` to print that . Instead use a `print_r`

```
print_r($j['miningSpeeds'][2]);
```

Also , you missed a semicolon after your JSON data.

#### The working code..

```
<?php
$data = '{"error":null,"miningSpeeds":[{"coinTypeCode":"HXC","currentHash":"5 Gh/sec","miningTime":"The last coin switch was 4 minutes ago.","port":"Connect via port 3326 (Keccak)."},{"coinTypeCode":"LOT","currentHash":"9823 Kh/sec","miningTime":"The last coin switch was 44 minutes ago.","port":"Connect via port 3332 (Scrypt)."},{"coinTypeCode":"MZC","currentHash":"11 Th/sec","miningTime":"The last coin switch was 20 minutes ago.","port":"Connect via port 3331 (SHA256)."}]}';
$j = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($j['miningSpeeds'][2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the json string.

Also you have to tell the echo which field you want to output like:

```
echo $j['miningSpeeds'][0]['port'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a semi-colon and you were trying to echo an array - use `print_r()`

Working Code:

```
<?php 

$data = '{"error":null,"miningSpeeds":[{"coinTypeCode":"HXC","currentHash":"5 Gh/sec","miningTime":"The last coin switch was 4 minutes ago.","port":"Connect via port 3326 (Keccak)."},{"coinTypeCode":"LOT","currentHash":"9823 Kh/sec","miningTime":"The last coin switch was 44 minutes ago.","port":"Connect via port 3332 (Scrypt)."},{"coinTypeCode":"MZC","currentHash":"11 Th/sec","miningTime":"The last coin switch was 20 minutes ago.","port":"Connect via port 3331 (SHA256)."}]}';

$j = json_decode($data);

$mining_speeds = $j -> miningSpeeds;

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($mining_speeds);
```

This will print out the Mining Speeds object - you can then access different properties using:

```
echo 'Coin Type: '.$mining_speeds[2] -> coinTypeCode.'<br/>';
echo 'Hash: '.$mining_speeds[2] -> currentHash.'<br/>';
echo 'Time: '.$mining_speeds[2] -> miningTime.'<br/>';
echo 'Port: '.$mining_speeds[2] -> port.'<br/>';
```

By changing the number in `$mining_speeds` will allow you to access different array keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the key to access the values inside the array:

```
echo($j['miningSpeeds'][2]["coinTypeCode"]);
echo($j['miningSpeeds'][2]["currentHash"]);
echo($j['miningSpeeds'][2]["miningTime"]);
```